# Parse Dashboard|Server not reachable: unable to connect to server

Tags: android, android-studio, heroku, parse-server

I am trying to setup a parse server for the first time.

Am working on Windows.

I am able to launch the parse Dashboard but, it says 
Server not reachable: unable to connect to server

My command line is like:

> parse-dashboard --appId myappid --masterKey mymasterkey
>   --serverURL "myurl" --appName myappname

[image]

I copied the link and pasted it in my browser,
Then i got
[image]

I have provided the Details AppID,MasteKey, etc... exactly same in all the places they were needed.

I am trying to run the following code in android studio, so that the respective data could be viewed in Parse Dashboard

ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");

```
  gameScore.put("score", 1337);

  gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");

  gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);

  gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

      public void done(ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) 
          {
              Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
          } 
          else {
              Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
          }
      }
  });
```

It always goes to log SAVE FAILED

Comment: what is url ? localhost or hosted ?

Comment: my server url is https://www.opinionhub645.herokuapp.com/parse/

Comment: can you fixed? I'm installed to localhost. i have a similar problem.